# bazel workspace for non-bazel packages

Tags: graphviz, bazel

I am using a package [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/) as part of a service and to use it I begin the bazel [WORKSPACE](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/workspace.html) file like this

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "graphviz",
    path = "/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.49.1",
    build_file_content = """
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
    name = "headers",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.dylib"]),
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"])
)
"""
)

...
```

The problem with it is its depends upon `graphviz` being downloaded, pre-installed and present in the path `/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.49.1`. Is there a way to make it part of the bazel build process such that if its not present it will be fetched and put in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `http_archive` to download one of graphviz's release archives:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/repo/http.html#http_archive

From https://graphviz.org/download/source/ the 2.49.1 release is available at https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4207231/packages/generic/graphviz-releases/2.49.1/graphviz-2.49.1.tar.gz

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
  name = "graphviz",
  url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4207231/packages/generic/graphviz-releases/2.49.1/graphviz-2.49.1.tar.gz",
  strip_prefix = "graphviz-2.49.1",
  sha256 = "ba1aa7a209025cb3fc5aca1f2c0114e18ea3ad29c481d75e4d445ad44e0fb0f7",
  build_file_content = """

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
    name = "headers",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.dylib"]),
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"])
)

""",
)
```

To answer the "if its not present" part of the question, I'm not aware of a straight forward way to accomplish automatically switching between something that's locally installed and downloading something. `http_archive` will always download the archive, and `new_local_repository` will always use something local.

There's the `--override_repository` flag, which replaces a repository with a local one, e.g. `--override_repository=graphviz=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.49.1` would effectively replace the `http_archive` with a `local_repository` pointing to that path. However, bazel would then expect there to be a WORKSPACE file and BUILD file already at that location (i.e., there's no way to specify `build_file_content`)

You could specify both repository rules in the WORKSPACE file, and then use some indirection, a Starlark flag, and a `select()` to switch between the repositories using a command-line flag. It's a little involved though, and also not automatic. Something like this:

WORKSPACE:

```
http_archive(
  name = "graphviz-download",
  ...,
)
new_local_repository(
  name = "graphviz-installed",
  ...,
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.1.1/bazel-skylib-1.1.1.tar.gz",
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.1.1/bazel-skylib-1.1.1.tar.gz",
    ],
    sha256 = "c6966ec828da198c5d9adbaa94c05e3a1c7f21bd012a0b29ba8ddbccb2c93b0d",
)
load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")
bazel_skylib_workspace()
```

BUILD (e.g. in //third_party/graphviz):

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:common_settings.bzl", "bool_flag")
bool_flag(
    name = "use-installed-graphviz",
    build_setting_default = False,
)

config_setting(
  name = "installed",
  flag_values = {
    ":use-installed-graphviz": "True",
  }
)

alias(
  name = "headers",
  actual = select({
    ":installed": "@graphviz-installed//:headers",
    "//conditions:default": "@graphviz-download//:headers",
  })
)
```

Then your code depends on `//third_party/graphviz:headers`, by default the alias will point to the downloaded version, and the flag `--//third_party/graphviz:use-installed-graphviz` will switch it to the installed version:

```
$ bazel cquery --output build //third_party/graphviz:headers
alias(
  name = "headers",
  actual = "@graphviz-download//:headers",
)

$ bazel cquery --output build //third_party/graphviz:headers --//third_party/graphviz:use-installed-graphviz
alias(
  name = "headers",
  actual = "@graphviz-installed//:headers",
)
```

Another option is to write (or find) a custom repository rule that combines the functionality of `http_archive` and `local_repository`, but that would probably be a fair bit of work.

Generally I think most people just use an `http_archive` and download the dependencies, and if there are specific needs for being offline or caching, there's `--distdir` for using already-downloaded artifacts for remote repository rules: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/guide.html#distribution-files-directories

Edit: An example of using rules_foreign_cc with graphviz:

WORKSPACE:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    sha256 = "69023642d5781c68911beda769f91fcbc8ca48711db935a75da7f6536b65047f",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-0.6.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/0.6.0.tar.gz",
)
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")
# This sets up some common toolchains for building targets. For more details, please see
# https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.6.0/flatten.html#rules_foreign_cc_dependencies
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

http_archive(
  name = "graphviz",
  url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4207231/packages/generic/graphviz-releases/2.49.1/graphviz-2.49.1.tar.gz",
  strip_prefix = "graphviz-2.49.1",
  sha256 = "ba1aa7a209025cb3fc5aca1f2c0114e18ea3ad29c481d75e4d445ad44e0fb0f7",
  build_file_content = """\
filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)
```

BUILD:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "configure_make")

# see https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.6.0/configure_make.html
configure_make(
    name = "graphviz",
    lib_source = "@graphviz//:all_srcs",
    out_shared_libs = ["libcgraph.so"], # or other graphviz libs
)

cc_binary(
  name = "foo",
  srcs = ["foo.c"],
  deps = [":graphviz"],
)
```

foo.c:

```
#include "graphviz/cgraph.h"

int main() {
  Agraph_t *g;
  g = agopen("G", Agdirected, NULL);
  agclose(g);
  return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ bazel build foo
INFO: Analyzed target //:foo (0 packages loaded, 2 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.229s, Critical Path: 0.06s
INFO: 7 processes: 5 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 7 total actions
```

Comment: just one question.. how will bazel know how to build this since it is a non-bazel package?

Comment: You would use the `build_file` or `build_file_content` attributes of `new_local_repository` and `http_archive` to specify a BUILD file to use with that repository

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Graphvuz is a non-bazel library So it does not have a build file. It uses cmake.

Comment: So usually you would need to write a BUILD file to build graphiz, and use that for `build_file`. If the build is complex, you might need to fork graphviz, or vendor it in your own repository. Or perhaps someone has already published appropriate BUILD files. Another option is to use rules_foreign_cc which enables bazel to build a cmake-based project: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.6.0/cmake.html That might be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm a newbie at this, can you provide how to do this in the answer?

Comment: I added a small example of using rules_foreign_cc with graphviz

Comment: I've continued this question here if you have additional advice about enumerating the deps using this framework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69741839/enumerate-graphviz-dependencies-for-bazel-build-with-foreign-rules-cc